# Using nested value as task_id in logstash aggregate filter

Tags: logstash

I am trying to merge logs using the `aggregate` filter and am facing some issues. Prior to using the `aggregate` filter, I have used `json` filter to parse the content of the log. The field I want to use as the `task_id` is actually nested. I tried using dot notation and it failed:

```
if [msg] == "Incoming request" {
  aggregate {
  task_id => "%{content.request_id}"
  code => "map['incoming_content'] = event['content']"
  }
}
```

As proof that nothing else is wrong, I tried with top-level field: `task_id => "%{clientip}"`. In this case the logs merged correctly.

How can I get the `aggregate` filter to aggregate logs based on a nested value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [bracket syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#logstash-config-field-references) as explained int he official documentation.

Try this:

```
if [msg] == "Incoming request" {
  aggregate {
  task_id => "%{[content][request_id]}"
  code => "map['incoming_content'] = event['content']"
  }
}
```